# EmberJS config prod img src url

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, handlebars.js, ember-cli

```
 Ember      : 1.13.6
 Ember Data : 1.13.7
```

I need to be able to set a global property and use it inside my .hbs files. Lets say for production I need serve images from another server but developing locally they can be severed relative to the project.

```
<img src="{{imgSrc}}/spinner.gif" alt="Loading..."/>
```

How can I set a global property or config and use it inside my .hbs files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I was able to come up that seems to work but no idea if it's a "good idea".

**config/environment.js** - set configurable `imgSrc` property for envs

```
module.exports = function(environment) {
  var ENV = {
    //...

    APP : {
      imgSrc: '/prod/path/to/assets/'
    }

    //...
  };

  if (environment === 'development') {
    ENV.APP.imgSrc = 'assets/images/';
  }
```

**app.js** - make `imgSrc` property available within app

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import Resolver from 'ember/resolver';
import loadInitializers from 'ember/load-initializers';
import config from './config/environment';

var App;

//...

App = Ember.Application.extend({
  modulePrefix: config.modulePrefix,
  podModulePrefix: config.podModulePrefix,
  Resolver: Resolver,
  imgSrc: config.APP.imgSrc
});

//...

export default App;
```

----- **Create a component called `img-src`** -----

**templates/components/img-src.hbs**

```
<img src="{{imgSrc}}{{image}}" alt="{{alt}}"/>
```

**components/img-src.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
   tagName: 'div',
   imgSrc: myApp.imgSrc
});
```

**hbs component usage**

```
{{img-src image="spinner.gif" alt="Loading..."}}
```

Does this took about right?